# Android: How to show automatically the whole item selection in a Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have an horizontal recycler view. When I select the last **visible** (right or left) I would like to see automatically it totally.

For example, if I select the "5" item, today I have this behavior:

[image]

And I would like this behavior:

[image]

Comment: i am a little confused of this you speak of?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to manually add right margin to your last view, simply call findLastCompletelyVisibleItem from your adapter, if that view is the last item in your recyclerview , get that child , and add some padding + margin (around 10dp) to that view, to bring it left. Then call notifyItemChanged to signal re validation of the layout.